# need clarification on Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need your help on this. In my copde I am using data table ... manually creating rows/columns in DT and populating them and lastly binding it to GridView.

I want to add a cell to each datarow in data table and the cell in turn will hold a HTML Control (HTML Anchor Tag).

Say, my current DT has 2rows and 3 cols as below

```
server  blah  blah
abc     xyz   123
def     vbh   345
```

Now, I want to do further processing on servername (on col1) and add a extra col to DT which will hold HTML Anchor Tag. the details can be seen clicking on the HTML Anchor tag. So, ultimately the DT should look like below:

```
server  blah  blah 
abc     xyz   123   HTML LINK
def     vbh   345   HTML LINK
```

Please tell how can I do this? i.e, add a separate cell to DT and add the HTML control to that bewly added cell.

Thanks.
Rahul

Comment: Would you mind marking some of your questions as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to create a model class that you can bind to that wraps each data row:

```
public class FooView
{
   public FooView(Row row)
   {
      this.Row = row;
   }

   private Row Row { get; set; }

   public string Server { get { (string)return this.Row["Server"]; } }
   public string Blah{ get { (string)return this.Row["blah"]; } }
   public string Link1{ get { string.Format("http://foo.bar/id={0}", this.Server); } }
}
```

Create a list of these and bind directly to this collection (using the Link1 property to get the href for the link).

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with RQDQ, here is an alternative method:

```
Dim newColumn As New Data.DataColumn("HyperlinkColumn")
    dt.Columns.Add(newColumn)

    For Each r As Data.DataRow In dt.Rows
        r("HyperlinkColumn") = "http://www.whatevervalue.com"
    Next
```

Where dt is the Datatable you are using.